# Why doesn't powershell wait until a command has been completed

Tags: powershell

If I have the below code, I find that Powershell doesnt seem to wait until the Get-ADGroupMember has finished.

```
$Groups = "Group1", "Group2"

foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | Select Name
Write-Host "End of line"
}
```

From the above I would Expect to get the following (Considering my groups have the same users):

```
Mike Myers
Tim Sanders
Lucy Gray
End of line
Mike Myers
Tim Sanders
Lucy Gray
End of line
```

But instead I get:

```
End of line
Mike Myers
Tim Sanders
Lucy Gray
Mike Myers
Tim Sanders
Lucy Gray
End of line
```

Comment: This is a common question.  Write-host output seems to come out faster than pipeline output.  I can't find a great stackoverflow link about it though.  Here's a serverfault one:  https://serverfault.com/questions/693549/powershell-write-host-not-synchronous

Comment: `Write-Host` output is written directly to the host console, regular PowerShell output goes to the success output stream. PowerShell does not guarantee output order across streams, only within each stream.

Comment: as js2010 pointed out, the `*-Host` cmdlets write _directly_ to the console host.your other code is writing to the output stream ... and PoSh delays that for ~300 ms to see if there is anything more to group with it. the fix is to **_[A]_** not mix direct & indirect writes to the screen OR **_[B]_** pipe the indirect writes to `Out-Host` to force the item to the screen _right now_. [*grin*]

Comment: Bobybobp, please see the answer to the linked question for a detailed explanation (@Lee_Dailey's comment sums it up).